# MySQL - How to GROUP BY text content?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, having

I have a simple table similar to this. There are manufactures that make different types of cars; and every car has a model number (unique key)

```
maker   type    model
A       VAN      111
A       VAN      112
A       SEDAN    113
A       SUV      114
A       SUV      115
B       VAN      116
B       SUV      117
C       SEDAN    118
C       SEDAN    119
C       SEDAN    120
D       VAN      121
E       VAN      122
E       VAN      123
E       SEDAN    124
E       SUV      125
```

How can I SELECT manufacturers that produce only one type of car and more than one model? I've really racked my brain trying to cook up a way to do this. I think GROUP BY and HAVING clauses are relevant as is COUNT() function, but if try:

```
SELECT maker, type 
FROM table 
GROUP BY maker, type 
HAVING COUNT(type) = 1
```

it returns stuff like `A-SEDAN` and `B-VAN` (because they have only one model) which is not what I need. I need to get a row that has same value in 'type' column while having several models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *How can I SELECT manufacturers that produce only one type of car and more than one model?*

You could use:

```
SELECT maker, MAX(type) AS type
FROM tab
GROUP BY maker
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TYPE) = 1
   AND COUNT(DISTINCT MODEL) > 1;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/LXBUG38052)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔═══════╦═══════╗
║ maker ║ type  ║
╠═══════╬═══════╣
║ C     ║ SEDAN ║
╚═══════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: God you are amazing. Thanks a lot! I really have a long way to go yet.

Comment: I just did. I was so overwhelmed with emotions. Thanks:)